# Kibana graph for custom calculation against time

Tags: charts, kibana

I have network related statistical data. Using which I am calculating network load. Say for example (packet ip + packet op) per time unit.

When I plot the graph in Kibana, on Y axis I see all aggregation functions like count, percentile min, max etc. Instead of those aggregation functions I simply  want to see network load per minute/ second.

Note: To calculate network load I have created scripted field in that index.

Does anyone has any idea to plot a graph in Kibana with the field value(scripted/non scripted) on Y axis and time on X axis?

Comment: you can try to put on X axis a Date Histogram and in Y axis you can put a Sum with your scriptedField. If you have juste one value per unit time the sum will be the value of you field

Comment: It takes sum of all values of my scripted field. I have data for time intevals t1,t2,t3 .... tn but while displaying it displays only one dot. I added seconds as an interval.